# What does act(() => promise.resolve()) do exactly in my test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a few tests that have synchronous code since it uses fetch responses. When i don't have this line "await act(() => Promise.resolve());", i get this error. But once i add this line in, this error disappears and my test runs how its suppose to. I know its not a false positive because i checked the snapshot it logs into my terminal. But I'm confused about this one line. How does it target the promises in my app or is it just another way of writing a force settimeout function.

error

```
    console.error
      Warning: An update to authenticator inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
      
      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

test

```
    test('when click with no inputs will display a error message in the DOM', async () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<CreateForm />, {wrapper: AuthProvider});

        await act(() => Promise.resolve());

        fireEvent.click(getByText('Create'));

        expect(getByText('Please fill in all fields')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

Comment: It's a hacky way to write 'wait a bit'. That it uses act makes it take component state changes into account. It targets specifically promises because it uses a promise and resolves right after instantly resolved promises in the component took action.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @EstusFlask

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry to bring this question up again but im not really understanding how it specifically target promises, how would it know which promises its targeting, i assume what you just told me is that it targets the closest promise, which doesnt really make much sense. And i dont see anyone using this line. So is using act and promise this way not recommended?

Comment: It targets all promises that were resolved before `Promise.resolve()` resolves, i.e. all promises inside a component that instantly resolve on mount. They were created before it, they resolve before it. Most times `async act` is not needed because RTL asynchronous assertions already use act, but it's common. If there were visual indicator that the component is ready to receive clicks (not responding without a sign is bad for UX), you could wait for it instead.